# How to declare a nested variable of html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make below nested html tag variable work? Now alist is showing properly, but b_var is showing as [object object] on the web page.

```
var b_var = $(`<br/>
<span class="span-text">Division</span>
<select class="form-control selector-division">                          
</select>
<div></div>`);  

var alist = $(`<li class="item" data-id="">
            <span class="span-text">and</span>
            <div class="abc">`+b_var+ `</div>                    
            <div class="remove" title="Delete"></div>
            </li>`);
```

By the way, there are some other functions using b_var like below:

```
populate_divisions(b_var.find(".selector-division"), all_divisions_txn);
```

Comment: Use `appendChild()` instead.  Don't concatenate HTML together.

Comment: What is your purpose? :)

Comment: @Brad full answer please? I am new. Thx.

Comment: @ddss12 http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: b_var  = JSON.stringify(b_var ); can also be done to chnage obj to string

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing `[object object]` because you are trying to concatinate a jQuery object on to a string, which results in appending the string representation of the object which in this case is `[object object]`.

You would probably be better of by appending HTML on to the DOM by either using jQuery's `append()` method, or `appendChild()` from JavaScript's standard library.

You can find documentation on both here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp